# Import js file to webpack application js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

I have ruby project where I add typescript and webpacker

I have wrote typescript and make `rake assets:tsc`. So it compiles ts code to js.

Now I have welcome.js at folder `app/assets/javascripts/generated/welcome.js

Here is code of welcome.js

```
 var HelloWorld = /** @class */ (function () {
    function HelloWorld(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    HelloWorld.prototype.print = function () {
        alert("Hello World, " + this.name + "!");
    };
    return HelloWorld;
}());
new HelloWorld('John Doe').print();
//# sourceMappingURL=welcome.js.map
```

I need to import it to webpacker `application.js` for example. I cannot find any tutorial how to do this on ruby on rails.

how I can solve this?

**UPDATE**

I tried to wrote in `welcome.js`

```
export default HelloWorld;
```

And in `application.js` wrote `import HelloWorld from 'generated'`

And get this in console

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "generated"
>       at Object. (application.js:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 24a076357adc3b41e79b:19)
>       at Object.defineProperty.value (bootstrap 24a076357adc3b41e79b:62)
>       at bootstrap 24a076357adc3b41e79b:62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `application.js` inside `/app/javascripts/packs`? If so you should be able to write:

```
import { HelloWorld } from 'generated/welcome'
```

at the top of `application.js`, then you can include it in your layout with:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

I use this syntax in my JS classes:

```
export class HelloWorld { var HelloWorld = /** @class */ (function () { ...} }
```

Although you might want different class/function names.

Comment: Thanks. That's helps me so much!